# Resizing Ubuntu root partition installed in "Install inside Win" mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop i386 using "Install inside Windows" option. In the installation i dedicated 3GB for the root parition. Now i have a Windows 7 and a Ubuntu.

Currently, I need more space for the Ubuntu root parition (just 50MB freespace remained!). I realized the it is a simple 3GB file in the Windows and root parition is *virtually* in that file.

So it should be possible to increase the size of the root parition. But i cannot find any way for this.

I do not want to reinstall the my Ubuntu or add another partition. Is there any painless way to just increase the size of root parition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this section](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20do%20I%20resize%20the%20virtual%20disks?) of the Wubi guide on the Ubuntu wiki.

The reason for adding a second disk (mounted on `/home`) rather than resizing the original one is that this allows you to do it while booted into Ubuntu from the original virtual disk.

Otherwise you'll need to boot from a live CD, increase the size of the file itself, and resize the file system to fill the space. I can explain further if you're interested in following this route, but using the utility mentioned on the wiki seems a lot easier.

Also, your root file system typically doesn't keep on growing, but home does, so having a separate virtual disk for home seems like a good idea.